# Can DataFrame be accessed from different SparkSessions?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Can I access a `DataFrame` from different `SparkSession`s?

Comment: Global views can as long as the "root" session is alive. But in general multiple sessions are not the best idea.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** No, it's not possible to share a DataFrame between `SparkSessions`.

A `DataFrame` lives in one single `SparkSession` (just like a `RDD` within `SparkContext`) that defines its visibility scope. The owning `SparkSession` becomes an integral part of a `DataFrame` which you can see in the definition of [`Dataset` type constructor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L160):

```scala
class Dataset[T] private[sql](
    @transient val sparkSession: SparkSession,   // <-- here
    @DeveloperApi @InterfaceStability.Unstable @transient val queryExecution: QueryExecution,
    encoder: Encoder[T])
  extends Serializable {
```

You can access the `SparkSession` a `DataFrame` belongs to using `sparkSession` attribute:

```scala
scala> val df = Seq(1,2,3).toDF("id")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int]

scala> df.sparkSession
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@4832813d

scala> df.sparkSession == spark
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: how to fetch sparkSession from a existing df in PySpark ? df.sparkSession does not work in PySpark.

Comment: Don't know pyspark, but would guess SparkSession.get is also possible.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski are there any gotchas to using the SparkSession attached to a dataframe / dataset as opposed to using the spark session created at the start of the Spark program?

Comment: @OmkarNeogi Please ask a separate question since it's more than a comment. Thank you.

Comment: any reason why you can't do something like `sparkSession.createDataFrame(oldDf.rdd, oldDf.schema)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can always just write out the dataframe that you want to be used again, then read it in next time.

Comment: Can we write it out to a cache, so that the read by the other process is faster, as opposed to writing to disk?

Comment: @Victor not in any obvious way that i've found.

Answer (score 0):

One can "copy" a Dataset from one session to another. Suppose you have a dataset ds1 in session spark1, you want to use it in session spark2, you can do this:

```
Dataset ds2 = spark2.sql("select 1 dummy").join(ds1).drop("dummy")
```

By doing this, you have a copy of ds1 in session spark2.

Answer (score -2):

Use [Global_temp_view](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#global-temporary-view) & as it is session-scoped, do not terminate the session with which you have created the DataFrame.